# Use of trackAppOpenedInBackground - Android ParsePlatform

Tags: android, parse-platform

According to the [official documentation](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseAnalytics.html):

> Tracks this application being launched (and if this happened as the result of the user opening a push notification, this method sends along information to correlate this open with that push).

But I don't understand what exactly it "tracks" and what the consequences would be if we didn't use it.

**TL;DR:**
What is the usage of `ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground`?
What would be the consequences if we didn't use it in an app?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app starts from the MainActivty by default that too specifically from the onCreate() function, Either from scratch or opened from any push notification. But to open a particular activity in app, You can use [Firebase Dynamic Link](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links) or some other services, What `ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground` does is that it analyzes how the user starts the app, whether through a push notification or start from scratch or from any other method and will report the admin of the app, So that you can use the information for building business strategies.

Simply, It's for tracking how the user starts the app and collecting that information and sending to the app developer.